# Auto Restart SH script on crash?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

Hi there guys i have a server running a game I've created and it has three SH scripts that are required to run in separate terminals so what i wanna know is 2 things.

1:is there a way i can get a single script that i double click on and launch all three scripts to where i can see the shell (for Debugging)

2: Is there any way to have said scripts auto restart when they exit or crash? (for full automated access when the server is unattended by a dev)

Server Specs:
6gb ram 60gb SSD 6 core CPU
Ubuntu 14.04
with vnc for desktop control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a SH script for you.

```
running=1

finish()
{
    running=0
}

trap finish SIGINT

while (( running )); do
    // Execute the command here that starts your server.
    echo "Restarting server on crash.."
    sleep 5
done
```

You can run this script for each server in it's own `screen`. That way you can see the console output of each one. For example:

`screen -S YOURUNIQUENAME -m THESCRIPTABOVE.sh`

In order to detach from the screen, hit CTRL + A then CTRL + D. You can get back to the screen by using `screen -x YOURUNIQUENAME`

For a nice guide on using the `screen` command, see this article: http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/ . It even has a video to show how it's used.

Comment: When running this script i get the following error
     server.sh: running: not found
Any ideas?